# Mongo query for flitering in total mongodb

Tags: mongodb

```
{
    "_id":objectId(23651478),
    "name":"Tomatos",
    "company":"vikranth transports",
    "array":[
             {"title":"Vegetables"}
            ],
    "description":"Vegitables are good to health"
 },
 {
    "_id":objectId(45761244),
    "name":"Apples",
    "company":"jessy transports",
    "array":[
             {"title":"Fruits"}
            ]
    "description":"Fruits are good to health, vegitables are also good to health"
 },
 {
    "_id":objectId(45761244),
    "name":"Nepal apples",
    "company":"sai transports",
    "array":[
             {"title":"Vegetables-home-made"}
            ]
    "description":"Fruits are good to health, vegitables are also good to health"
 }
```

Above is my mongodb modal for my project requirement. Now what I want is I have to search for "title":"Fruits" only Fruits name should have to come and from the result I have to filter for company "jessy transports"

What I tried is

```
{"$text":{"$search":"jessy transports"}},{"array":{"$elemMatch":{"title":{"$in":[/Fruits/]}}}}
```

Here I used $text search because I am trying to search for "Fruits" in that. I tried to filter for "jessy transports". But I get all the "jessy transports" and then not filtered "Fruits"

Exactly what I want is when I search for "Fruits" I want to get all the Fruits that having "title":"Fruits" in array.

--> When I search for "Fruits" and in  that I want only the company name having "jessy transports" then i have to get al the Fruits that having jessy transports.

--> when I search for "Fruits" and in that I want only the company name having "jessy transports" and from the result I want a text search for "health"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
  db.YOUR_COLLECTION.aggregate(
    {$unwind:"$array"},
    {$match: {"array.title" :'fruits', 'company': 'jessy transports'}}).pretty()
```

use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and then match query.
It produces result like this

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58076939309f9df8e6b59573"),
"name" : "Apples",
"company" : "jessy transports",
"array" : {
    "title" : "Fruits"
},
"description" : "Fruits are good to health, vegitables are also good to health"
}
```